# textFieldShouldReturn not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfielddelegate

I have two classes. In one of them, the return key (for the virtual keyboard) works perfectly. In the other, it does not. As far as I can tell, the code is pretty much identical. Can someone help me figure out why my its not firing on the one that doesn't work?

**This one works:**

```
class ChangePasswordVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField == self.tempPasswordTextField {
            self.changeTempPasswordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        else if textField == self.changeTempPasswordTextField {
            self.confirmChangeTempPasswordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        else  {
            changePasssword()
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

**This one does not work:**

```
class ResetPasswordVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField == self.emailTextField {
            print("go button tapped")
            submitEmailForPasswordReset()
        }
        return true
    }

}
```

I put the print statement in to see if it fires at all but it doesn't print anything to the console.

Comment: Do you have the delegate set on the text field that doesn't work?

Comment: 99% of the time when this sort of stuff doesn't work is due to the delegate not being set

Comment: I don't but I don't have it set on the one that works either

Comment: @MichaelWilliams Yes, you do have it set in the one that works. If you didn't, it wouldn't be working.

Comment: ok. thanks for the help everyone

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have forgot probably some of the delegate settings, check for:

```
    self.tempPasswordTextField.delegate = self
    self.changeTempPasswordTextField.delegate = self
    self.confirmChangeTempPasswordTextField.delegate = self
    self.emailTextField.delegate = self
```

In your code especially check the last (`self.emailTextField`).

Comment: I have the same issue. But weird part is that the delegates are all good to go. Still `textFieldShouldReturn` does not work. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set UITextField delegate either using StoryBoard/XIB or using code. It will work fine when UITextField delegate assigned correctly.